# Numerical Recipes in C spline and splint confused

Tags: c, spline, numerical

I want to transform my Matlab procedure to C, and there is a function `spline`, and I have used the function provided by Numerical Recipes in C(3.3).
In matlab:

```
        step = 0.1;
        N_L=1024;
        xx=[1:step:N_L];
        x=[1:N_L];

        Rtp=spline(x,Rt,xx);
```

And in the book, there are two functions, `spline` and `splint`:

```
void spline(float x[], float y[], int n, float yp1, float ypn, float y2[])
void splint(float xa[], float ya[], float y2a[], int n, float x, float *y)
```

The parameters of these two functions confuse me. I have seen the introduction below the function, but still, don't know what does n, yp1 and ypn mean. If I want to achieve the same function like Matlab, how should I define the parameters?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The documentation of the parameters in that book is excellent. Which part specifically is confusing? Note that the numerical recipes professors use 1-based arrarys, since they were FORTRAN dudes.

Comment: @Bathsheba I set yp1 ypn to zero, and invoke function like :spline(xx, Rt,N_L,0,0,y2);   then   splint(xx, Rt, y2, N_L, 0, y);   xx is unit-offset :1.and the first y I get are not the same with Rt[0].

Comment: The `spline()` function in Numerical Recipes does a clamped spline, with `yp1` and `ypn` the first-derivatives at the endpoints (or endpoint slopes); optionally, you can signal it to do a natural spline (with vanishing second-derivatives at the endpoints) by setting one or both of `yp1` and `ypn` >= 1e30. My understanding is that the Matlab `spline()` uses different boundary conditions (no natural spline), but [can do a clamped spline](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com#bvjdtse).

Comment: @DavidBowling  Thanks guy,I just don't know how to confirm the yp1 or ypn.I mean I just know two params:xx and Rt,I don't have the function right?so how could I know yp1 or ypn,if they are derivatives ,they can only get from function which I don't know,this confusing me.

Comment: Those are parameters that you choose to suit your needs: you choose the slope of the interpolating function at the endpoints. You can choose 0 for both, but this is not the same thing as a natural spline. I believe the default for Matlab `spline()` is completely different, using third-derivatives; there are several ways to do cubic spline interpolation. If you follow the link I provided in my last comment, I think you can use Matlab's `spline()` differently than you have in posted code to match the Numerical Recipes method.

Comment: @DavidBowling  Thanks very much,that helps,I will try to see that.Very appreaciate.